# Comparing msg.value using javascript test always fails

Tags: truffle

So I have this solidity function:

```
function claimGoodTest(uint256 typeId) public payable {
    if (msg.value < 4000) revert();
}
```

I test it with the following:

```
var result = await contract.claimGoodTest(typeId, {
    from: accounts[0], value: web3.utils.toWei('40', 'ether')
}, function(result) { })
```

I get this :

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
```

Why is this happening ?  This seems like a bug or I have the wrong syntax.

Comment: If you comment out the `if (msg.value < 4000) revert();` line, do you still see a problem? (I'm trying to narrow down whether it's that line causing the `revert`.)

Comment: May be you should try: `if (msg.value < 4000) { revert(); }`

Comment: If i comment out that line then there is no revert and the function works.  If i add curly braces there is no effect.  Perhaps my syntax on the JS side is wrong ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this... could you share the code for how you instantiate `contract`?

Comment: Which version of web3 are you using?

Comment: Im using:
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
"web3": "^1.0.0-beta.27"

It seems that my accounts[0] has about 93 ether in balance.

Answer (score 1):

Oh!  I just had to switch the order of the test parameters.  The object with value should be the very last param.  The callback needed to be the second to last.  This is not documented well.

> var result =   await contract.claimGoodTest(  typeId ,
>   function(){} ,{ value:web3utils.toWei('0.00001','ether') })

Comment: Is `contract` a Truffle thing? The syntax you're using doesn't match up with web3.js 1.0.0, which uses promises instead of callback functions. web3.js 0.2x.x would have had the callback function as the last parameter. So `contract` must be something else, and I'm guessing Truffle?